# ListFragment vs Fragment: implementation best practices using loaders, adapters, views

Tags: android

I have implemented **ListFragment** with **ListView** using my custom classes based on **AsyncTaskLoader** and **ArrayAdapter**, method `setListAdapter(adapter)` and also my custom view class for a list item as it is proposed by [android documentation and samples](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

Now at **onListItemClick** I navigate to details activity for the item with Fragment.

What is the best practices / classes I should use here to implement details form?

I know I can still use **AsyncTaskLoader** (which is loading data from web service for me) but do I also need adapter? Which one?

Maybe there is an sample in Internet?

I have found a lot of samples (including in SDK) for how to create list form but not for details form with loaders.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link.... use listfragments for details....

http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/